# Extracting financial tables embedded in PDF document

Tags: python, excel, pdf, extract, finance

I am trying to **parse annual reports** of companies, that are in pdf format (from annualreports.com). I have downloaded approximately 5000 pdf docs, each with text and table data. I wish to **extract the financial data tables** found within these pdf documents and **save them to an excel file**.

I have tried solutions based on Tabula, PyPDF2, Regexp and NLTK
Yet every time, I seem to get false positives (characters not detected, correct page in pdf not extracted, etc.) in my solutions. Are there any python solutions for this problem? Also willing to explore solutions in other languages (like VBA maybe?)

Here are a few examples of the documents I am dealing with

http://annualreports.com/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/a/NYSE_ATEN_2015.pdf
http://annualreports.com/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/a/NASDAQ_AEIS_2016.pdf
http://annualreports.com/HostedData/AnnualReportArchive/A/LSE_ALM_2016.pdf

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Provide the snippet of what and how you tried and the error message you are getting, we will be able to give you better solution to your approach then.

Comment: I have used Tabula-py to parse tables from PDF. Try to tweak params and see what it outputs. For another solution, take a look at https://layout-parser.github.io/